# Is an event triggered when a UITextField with secureTextEntry = YES is cleared?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uicontrolevents

I have a UITextField instance with `secureTextEntry = YES`. When the field first gains focus any keypress will clear the field, as appears to be standard behavior on iOS.

As far as I can tell, `UIControlEventEditingChanged` is not triggered. I have also tried subscribing to `UIControlEventAllEditingEvents` but it appears not to be triggered. This is causing an issue for me since I'm relying on knowing when the field is edited to set the `enabled` attribute of a UIButton.

Is there an event which is fired when the field is cleared in this way?

They context around my issue can be seen in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/779).

Comment: It works for me. I have a text field. If I make it secure entry and I add an action for the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event, my action is called when I tap a key and the text field is cleared.

Comment: Confirmed that this works with iOS 6.1; the issue appears to be with the version of iOS I'm targeting.

Comment: Please submit this as an answer.

Comment: What version are you having the issue with?

Comment: One I can't talk about here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UITextField's delegate:

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    return YES;
}

- (void) updateButton {
    someButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I add an action for `UIControlEventAllEvents`, the method does not get called when the text field is cleared in this way which confirms that no event is triggered.

Comment: This was receiving flags for reading like a comment more than an answer. I've undeleted it, but see if you can clarify it beyond a simple remark "which confirms that no event is triggered", which can be easily missed.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use the following Method:

```
 - (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
        [self performSelector:@selector(MakeButtonEnabled:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
        return YES;
    }

- (void) MakeButtonEnabled:(id)sender {
    UIButton *yourButton=(UIBUtton*) sender;
    yourBUtton.enabled = NO;
}
```

hope this will help you.